# Mini mobile robot with mini PC

Tags: ros, hardware, robot, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make a mini mobile robot with a mini PC which can run ubuntu.

Is there any opensource hardware product?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223269/mini-mobile-robot-with-mini-pc/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think a convenient solution is using a Raspberry Pi 2 for your robot. ROS can now be installed using Ubuntu 14.04 for ARM (see [Ubuntu install instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) and [ROS Ubuntu Arm install instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM)).

Using this approach, the amount of fiddling with toolchains, compilation etc. is fairly minimal. The system is very lightweight and small and can for instance be powered conveniently via a powerbank during experiments.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2016-01-03**:
Thank you so much. Could you recommend a mini mobile robot platform?
I want to use Arduino Robot, but the product is end-of-life.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-01-04**:
I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but you can get a "2WD arduino robot" chassis (google it) starting at about ~15 US$. You can also order a Arduino clone (~10 US$) and motor shield clone (~10 US$) from China. This is about the cheapest option that comes to mind :)

**Comment by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on 2016-01-04**:
Thank you so much. I want SLAM and navigation using RP-Lidar. A good wheel encoder is a must, which will be used for localization(amcl) although mapping algorithms, such as hector_slam, do not need it.